# Regex to retrieve value from table

Tags: regex, string, powershell

We have users replying on an e-mail and we need to retrieve the date mentioned in the table.

For the moment I made the following code to do that for us:

```
$temp = ($Mail.Body.Text -creplace '(?m)^\s*\r?\n' -split "User name`r`n`tLogon name`r`n`tEnd date`r`n`tNew end date")[1]
(($temp -split "`r`n`t")[3] -split "`r`n")[0]
```

As you can see, it's quite long and very much relying on `-split`. Is there an easier way to retrieve the date? With `Select-String` or a `Regex` or something?

The table format in the e-mail is always the same, as the users needs to fill in the date in the HTML table. So we need to be able to read that table. In the example below the result would be `01/08/2016`.

Example of such an e-mail:

```
Date added below



From: GBR Service Desk 
Sent: Wendesday 29 juni 2016 7:00
To: Bond, James (London) GBR
Subject: REMINDER Expiring user: 
Importance: High



Dear James

This is a reminder e-mail to inform you that the following Windows user account will expire soon:

User name

    Logon name

    End date

    New end date


Smith, Jobn (Manchester) GBR

    jent

    01/07/2016

    01/08/2016



Because you are registered as the manager of this user, we would like to ask you to verify if this account is still nee
ded after its end date. More text...

Yours sincerely
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Select-String` to find date-like patterns and select the last one:

```
$EndDate = ($Mail.Body.Text |Select-String '\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}' -AllMatches).Matches[-1].Value
```

Comment: That's a really great tip! Thank you Mathias :) But sometimes they type something there like say "8 augustus". In that case I need to have that to..

Comment: @DarkLite1: And how many formats/human languages are you going to support? Add that to the question body.